# Split PDF documents into separate pages using PHP (or possibly perl)

Tags: php, perl, pdf, split

Can anybody point me towards a PHP library or script that would allow me to split a pdf consisting of multiple pages into separate files, each containing 1 page.  The PDFLib documentation doesn't appear to allow this and Google hasn't been particularly helpful.

I could possibly also use Perl, but it would be very inconvenient to do so.

Comment: This is very, very hardly going to be possible in PHP. Consider 3rd party tools. What platform are you on?

Comment: TCPDF is native PHP and probably will do this...

Comment: I eventually used fpdf combined with fpdi which allowed me to extract a particular page and use it as a template for a new blank page.

Comment: fab. thanks for posting the follow up...

Comment: This question is about using PHP to split PDF documents - a valid programming question, not necessarily (just) about the use of tools or libraries.  I've nominated it for reopening.

Answer (score 9):

I have used [PDF::Reuse](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/PDF::Reuse). It makes it so easy it is not even funny. Here is the relevant snippet from one of my scripts:

```
while ( my $line = <$page_list> ) {
    chomp $line;
    my ($class, $drug, $page) = split ' ', $line;

    my $dir = canonpath( catfile $OUTPUT_DIR, $class );
    mkdir $dir unless -e $dir;

    my $target = canonpath( catfile $dir, "$drug.pdf" );

    prFile( $target );
    prCompress( 1 );
    prDoc( $INPUT_PDF, $page, $page + 1 );
    prEnd();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It's not perl or php, but [pdftk](http://www.accesspdf.com/pdftk/) easily does this and much more.

Answer (score 3):

See [PDF::Extract CPAN module for Perl](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?PDF::Extract).

Comment: Your exact case is the example on the PDF::Extract manual page.

Answer (score 1):

Does [TCPDF](http://www.tecnick.com/public/code/cp_dpage.php?aiocp_dp=tcpdf) do what you want? It is native PHP.

Answer (score 1):

I would vote for using PDFTk even if you choose to call it PDFTk from PHP. It has excellent track record of how to do this. The following example shows how to split your PDF with PDFTk

```
pdf2json.exe Paper.pdf -enc UTF-8 -compress -split 10 Paper.pdf_%.js
```

(example taken from [this url](http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/docs_publishing_html5.jsp))