# Split multi page PDF file into single pages

Tags: php, linux, pdf, split

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Split PDF documents into separate pages using PHP (or possibly perl)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2584133/split-pdf-documents-into-separate-pages-using-php-or-possibly-perl)

How can I split a multi-page PDF file into distinct single page PDF files in PHP on Linux server? Are there any PHP libraries or free command line tools available to do this?

Comment: @MartinSchröder   Can we do it using node.js?

Comment: This might help - https://stackoverflow.com/a/62794653/12731030

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most recent version of [**Ghostscript** (v9.06)](http://downloads.ghostscript.com/) can do this too. Here is the commandline to be used inside a `cmd.exe` 'DOS-Box' window on a 32-bit Windows system:

```
 gswin32c.exe                ^
   -o original_page_%03d.pdf ^
   -sDEVICE=pdfwrite         ^
   -sPDFSETTINGS=/prepress   ^
    original-multipage.pdf
```

**`-o ...`**: this indicates the name of the output file(s).
**`%03d`**: this part of the filename will be translated into 3-digit numbers, padded by leading `0`s, starting from `001` for the first page.
**`-sPDFSETTINGS=...`**: is an optional parameter; if used will ensure that all used fonts are embedded and some other settings which in general ensure a high quality output.

Ghostscript is available for Windows. (The link above leads you to the installers: **gs906w32.exe** and **gs906w64.exe**. Scroll down to find them...).

Comment: Does this snippet will work on windows with ghostscript v9.05?

Comment: Kurt, can you please explain it a bit more. I didn't get it. Thanks

Comment: @MuhammadQasim: Why, do you think, did I explicitely write *'the most recent version of Ghostscript'*? And why did I even quote that version, you think?! -- So no, it doesn't work with v9.05.

Comment: @MuhammadQasim: I updated the answer to add some better explanation of the individual parameters used.

Comment: @MuhammadQasim: Do you need that for Linux (as you say in your question) or Windows or ...?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Pdftk](http://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-cli-examples/)

```
exec("pdftk " . $pdflargeFile . " burst output " . $outputPath);
```

Comment: can this be used on windows also???

Comment: yes it runs on windows  see http://www.pdflabs.com/docs/install-pdftk/

Comment: It didn't work. Are you sure its for splitting pdf file or for joining???

Comment: See : http://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-cli-examples/  `Split Select Pages from Multiple PDFs into a New Document
pdftk A=one.pdf B=two.pdf cat A1-7 B1-5 A8 output combined.pdf`

Comment: Use `pdftk largepdfile.pdf burst` and tell me that you get

Comment: Yes thats what I wanted but using "burst" in this way also creates a text file. Anyway to escape this?

Comment: OK. Will I be able to use it on Linux in the same way? if not what I would need to change?

Comment: @Muhammad Qasim it something simple and not enough for you to change

Comment: I think .exe will not run on Linux (don't know much about Linux), how to install it for Linux and how to add it to the PATH?

Comment: It Supporst Linux FeeBDS , Ubuto or SuSE RMP .... already given you installation link http://www.pdflabs.com/docs/install-pdftk/

Answer (score 0):

[PDFSplit](http://pdfbox.apache.org/commandlineutilities/PDFSplit.html) has all the examples you need. :)

```
PDFSplit -split 1 sample_with_13_pages.pdf
```

.. should do it.

Comment: if it does require java it should have been specified in the answer