# How do I output separate pdf/tiff files for each individual pages from a large xml file?

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I am using xsl-fo to generate pdf/tiff files. I want to output separate pdf/tiff files for each individual pages from a large xml file. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I would use fop to create a pdf with a separate page for each item in the xml file and then use a split tool to break it into separate documents.

Look at this issue for info on how to break it apart: [Split multi page PDF file into single pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12744616/split-multi-page-pdf-file-into-single-pages)